# Why do my unwrapped UVs appear outside of the UV canvas?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to texture a model from a video game, but when I use Unwrap some of the UVs appear outside of the canvas,

[image: UV Error]

and are not included when I export the UV map for editing in Photoshop.

[image: Export Error]

I could fix this by translating the UVs onto the canvas, but they wouldn't all fit, and I don't know how/if it is possible to resize the canvas manually.

As you could guess I am quite new to 3D modeling - any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: did you unwarp the whole thing? Or just a sword? you can move thing in uv editor by pressing G and scale by pressing S

Comment: The model itself is several meshes, so here I only unwrapped the sword mesh. I'll try scaling the meshes to fit them on the canvas - I just wish I knew why they appeared off-canvas in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that something went wrong in a proccess of your unwrapping since there is that line that take up all the space in your grid. Maybe missed some seems? Though, for a sword blade i would use project from view

It also appears that tou havent applied the scale for you mesh. If you ever rescale, rotate or move around your object (in object mode i believe), you have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> while you have your object selected in object mode and select one of the options you need.

If you are unsure what you have changed, while having your cursor inside the 3D View area (where you can see your objects basically), press <kbd>N</kbd> and in the window that came out of the right side, check if the locations and rotations are all set to 0 and if the scales are all set to 1. If they are not, that means you have been transforming your objects without applying the changes

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about applying the scale for my mesh, I'll be sure to do that.